# win32 retrieve index of all selected items from listview

Tags: c, winapi

does anyone know how to fix this
i wanna execute code  for every selected item in the list

```
            itemint=SendMessage(hwndList,LVM_GETNEXTITEM,-1,LVNI_SELECTED))
              {
                while (itemint != -1)
                  {
                    itemint =SendMessage(hwndList,LVM_GETNEXTITEM, itemint, LVNI_SELECTED);
                      //// 
                  }
```

which  fails to find first(with lowest index) item out of selected ones

Comment: And what happens with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to function calls to SendMessage. Write for loop as this.

```
for (itemInt = -1; (itemInt = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, itemInt , LVNI_SELECTED)) != -1; )
{
   // do work on selected item here
   DoIt(itemInt);
}
```

Comment: No. You meant to write: `for (itemInt = -1; (itemint = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, itemint, LVNI_SELECTED)) != -1; )`

Comment: No. It is still not correct. Look at the code in my comment, and then the code in your answer. There is still a difference.

Comment: While technically correct, the `for` loop clauses are difficult to decipher, and it's needlessly difficult to set breakpoints, or step over portions of the code in a debugger. C# allows to set breakpoints on individual expressions. You don't have that luxury in C++. [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094098/1889329) is equally correct, but more readable, and plays along better with the debugger's rules.

Answer (score 5):

Your iteration code is in essence correct. The problem is that you are doing your work after the second call to `SendMessage`, as evidenced by the placement of your comment line. Move the work to be before the second call to `SendMessage` and you won't skip the first selected item.

```
itemint = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, -1, LVNI_SELECTED))
{
    while (itemint != -1)
    {
        // do work on selected item here
        itemint = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, itemint, LVNI_SELECTED); 
    }
}
```

For what it is worth, your code would miss the first selected item, but also present you with a final item with index of -1.

Comment: Do you know if there is a faster version? I have a (virtual) listview with millions of items and the overhead makes this unusable...

Comment: Oh never mind, figured it out: `GWLP_WNDPROC` and then call the window procedure directly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is functionally the same as examples above. ListView_GetNextItem is just a convenient macro which translates to SendMessage LVM_GETNEXTITEM. I like this one for readability.

```
int itemint=-1;
while((itemint=ListView_GetNextItem(hwndList,itemint,LVNI_SELECTED))!=-1)
{
  ...
}
```

You will see in CommCtrl.h that it is defined like this:

```
#define ListView_GetNextItem(hwnd, i, flags) \
    (int)SNDMSG((hwnd), LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)(int)(i), MAKELPARAM((flags), 0))
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT Agree, comments added.