# ListView_GetNextItem always returning 0

Tags: c++, winapi

I have some code that currently causes an infinite loop and I'm unable to find an reason as to why.

The code is designed to set bit-flags on an integer based on items that are selected in the listbox.This is handled by the case statement within the While loop.

I've followed the code through on a debugger and the value of selectedItem never changes. The handle to the listbox appears to be valid and is populated using the same handle.

I've tried using both the SendMessage function and ListView_GetNextItem macro, former is commented out in my code.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious here!

Edit:
I was basing this loop off the one seen here:
[win32 retrieve index of all selected items from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093414/win32-retrieve-index-of-all-selected-items-from-listview)

```
int getTypeStatus()
{
    int retVal =0;
    //int selectedItem = SendMessage(lstFileStatus, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)-1, MAKELPARAM(LVIS_SELECTED,0));
    int selectedItem = ListView_GetNextItem(lstFileStatus,-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
    while (selectedItem != -1)
    {
        switch (selectedItem){
        case 0:
            retVal = retVal | NOT_VERIFIED;
            break;
        case 1:
            retVal = retVal | IRRELEVANT;
            break;
        case 2:
            retVal = retVal | NOT_IN_LIST;
            break;
        case 3:
            retVal = retVal | CONFIRMED;
            break;
        case 4:
            retVal = retVal | NOT_CONFIRMED;
            break;
        case 5:
            retVal = retVal | NEWLY_IDENTIFIED;
            break;
        case 6:
            retVal = retVal | MISMATCH_DETECTED;
            break;
        }
        selectedItem = ListView_GetNextItem(lstFileStatus,selectedItem, LVNI_SELECTED);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Edit: Also included code for creating control and populating (which works)

```
lstFileStatus = CreateWindowEx(0,"ListBox","",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LBS_NOTIFY|WS_BORDER|LBS_EXTENDEDSEL,LeftHandStartX,TypeLineY,130,170,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_LBX_TYPESTATUS,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
if (!lstFileStatus) {outputControlOutputError("lstFileStatus");}
for (int i=0;i<numTypeStatus;i++)
{
    SendMessage(lstFileStatus,LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)arrayTypeStatus[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try `LVNI_SELECTED | LVNI_BELOW`?

Comment: Same result. Changed back to: 
SendMessage (lstFileStatus, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)-1, MAKELPARAM(LVNI_SELECTED,0))
and
SendMessage (lstFileStatus, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)selectedItem, MAKELPARAM(LVNI_SELECTED|LVNI_BELOW,0))
To test and have exact same result

Comment: You're getting list views and listboxes mixed up. They are different controls. LVM_GETNEXTITEM is a listview message. Listbox messages begin with LB_xxx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LVM_GETNEXTITEM` is a listview control message, but your control is a listbox. They're different controls and the messages aren't interchangable.

To get the selected items from a multi-select listbox you need to use `LB_GETSELCOUNT` to get the number of selections, allocate an array of ints that size, and then use `LB_GETSELITEMS` to get the selection indices.

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid! Thanks for the help!